# How can I check if an entity's attribute/entire entity has changed in Spring Data JPA, after I fetched it from the DB, to make some changes to it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How can I check the change of an Entity in Spring Data JPA?
Also, check if a particular attribute in an Entity has changed?

Comment: Spring Data JPA is just a wrapper it still uses Hibernate so use your regular way of checking.

Comment: In Spring Data JPA, I use a repository to save and fetch a model from DB, that is different from using a Hibernate Session.
Any pointers, how can I get the current Hibernate session, when working with Spring JPA Repositories?, so I can check if a particular Model is dirty?

Comment: No it isn't different. Underneath it is still the same.

Comment: Hmm I get your point, but the thing is that, in some controller class, I fetch a Model class, and at some point I need to check if that instance is changed or not.
I'm not able to understand how should I check if that particular model instance is changed. Even if I have the Hibernate session, I'm not sure, how would the isDirty check work here.
Any pointers?